# Help Finding this Font or one similar

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Does anyone know what this font is or a similar font to this?

please please help

Comment: Please review our Font Identification guidelines and edit your question: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions

Comment: Just a suggestion but if you're going to post a question in regards to typography please make sure to upload the correct orientation where someone can read the font.

Answer (score 2):

It probably [Herald Square NF Font](http://www.dafont.com/heraldsquare.font?text=Custom%20Cake)

[image]

Comment: That's a definite match. If that photo is as old as it looks, though, I'm guessing the font came well after the sign.